# MySQL: "INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM other_table LEFT JOIN other_table2" weak performance

Tags: mysql, insert-into, materialized-views, sqlperformance

I want to create a materialized view in MySQL but the INSERT INTO performance annoys me.
My baseTable has 1,1 million rows -> ascending trend.
I got a SELECT query that reads the data of the baseTable and does little calculations and three other joins on top. (~30sec <- it's ok! it will be executed one time at night)
BUT: as soon as I write "INSERT INTO" before the select statement it takes more than 2 hours and will maybe never terminate (I didn't try longer) -> KILL 'process-id'

I got a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO materialized_view
SELECT id, ..., other_table.value3 
FROM baseTable 
LEFT JOIN other_table 
LEFT JOIN other_table2
LEFT JOIN other_table3
```

Is someone able to help me? :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp1 AS SELECT..." by using the same select. Or insert into a newly created table without any indices. This should take only a bit longer than the SELECT. If it is the case, the problem is not the insertion itself, but the "materialized_view" table. Maybe it has too many indices, or it is locked, whatever. Enable profiling and do a smaller INSERT INTO SELECT to investigtate.

Comment: I already tried
"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS materialized_view;
CREATE TABLE materialized_view 
  SELECT id, ..., other_table.value3 
  FROM baseTable 
  LEFT JOIN other_table 
  LEFT JOIN other_table2
  LEFT JOIN other_table3;"
I read "temporary" brings no speed up.
And of course it was not fixed after this try.
materialized_view has only one index -> ID.

Comment: OK. So the SELECT takes 30s but the insert is very slow. How did you time the SELECT? Do any other processes do reads from materialized_view table in the meantime?

Comment: No, I'm in a developer environment and the only user who access. I check also "SHOW PROCESSLIST" before and it's empty.

Comment: Damn. How did you time the SELECT? Did you really display 1M rows in the MySQL window? Is the machine loaded? (try vmstat)

Comment: "How did you time the SELECT?" -> I start it manually for test proposals. "Did you really display 1M rows in the MySQL window?" -> No. It shows only a small extract of ~500 rows. I use phpStorm for manually and later then it should be a daily "Talend" Job. "Is the machine loaded? (try vmstat)" -> what do you mean? It's hosted by our big IT and I got no database admin rights. I got no problems with other queries so far. Are 1mio rows (too) much for mysql?

Comment: If your tool only displays 500 rows then it most likely added a "LIMIT 500" to your query which makes it into something rather different. MYSQL can use different optimizations when using LIMIT. Your INSERT does not use LIMIT. So you are timing the wrong query, the problem is not the INSERT, it's the SELECT... Please post the entire query and the result of EXPLAIN.